# Broadcast Calendar Chronology approach

Tags: calendar, jodatime

Been reviewing the Chronology implementation in an effort to construct a Broadcast Calendar Chronology. Do you have any recommendations that might help in bringing me closer? BuddhistChronology which uses an offsetDateTimeField which appears to have the right idea, but would need some crafting around the month to month day calculations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_calendar